# alertdialog error with events

Tags: java, android, events, android-alertdialog, datarobot

**EDIT: Added an additional error and the revision to the code i made.**

I am new to java/android. I am trying to create an AlertDialog inside my SmartApp class when an event is fired in my DataRobot class. I am getting an error when doing this. The event is firing and calling the function successfully in SmartApp, but when it gets to `AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();` the following error is printed to logcat. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong or a better way to implement what i am wanting?

```
Logcat error:
02-05 22:39:27.081: VERBOSE/SmartApp(281): data alert event caught
02-05 22:39:27.081: VERBOSE/SmartApp(281): inside sendalert
02-05 22:39:27.090: WARN/System.err(281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-05 22:39:27.122: WARN/System.err(281):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
02-05 22:39:27.122: WARN/System.err(281):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
02-05 22:39:27.141: WARN/System.err(281):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
02-05 22:39:27.141: WARN/System.err(281):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:59)
02-05 22:39:27.161: WARN/System.err(281):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:786)
02-05 22:39:27.161: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp.sendAlert(SmartApp.java:169)
02-05 22:39:27.171: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$3.dataAlertReceived(SmartApp.java:59)
02-05 22:39:27.201: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataRobot.fireDataAlertEvent(DataRobot.java:96)
02-05 22:39:27.201: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataRobot.analyzeData(DataRobot.java:32)
02-05 22:39:27.211: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$1.dataReceivedReceived(SmartApp.java:45)
02-05 22:39:27.222: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.ConnectDevice.fireDataReceivedEvent(ConnectDevice.java:71)
02-05 22:39:27.222: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.ConnectDevice.run(ConnectDevice.java:42)
02-05 22:39:27.242: WARN/System.err(281):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

---

```
//my smartapp class main ui
public class SmartApp extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    TextView smartConnectionStatus;
    TextView testOutputView;
    Thread cThread;
    private ConnectDevice cD = new ConnectDevice();
    private DataRobot dR = new DataRobot();
    private DataBuilder dB = new DataBuilder();
    private DataSender dS = new DataSender();


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);



        cD.addDataReceivedListener(new DataReceivedListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataReceivedReceived(DataReceivedEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dR.analyzeData(event.getData());
            }
        });
        dR.addDataAlertListener(new DataAlertListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataAlertReceived(DataAlertEvent event) {
                Log.v("SmartApp", "data alert event caught");
                sendAlert();
            }
        });
    }
    /* Function for sending alerts that the user has exceeded a stress index */
    public void sendAlert() {
        Log.v("SmartApp", "inside sendalert");
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        Log.v("SmartApp", "after builder1");
        //Vibrator vibrator;
        //vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        //vibrator.vibrate(500);
        alert.setMessage("Testing alert dialog...");
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        Log.v("SmartApp", "after builder2");
        //AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setTitle("Title");
        Log.v("SmartApp", "after builder3");
        alert.show();
        Log.v("SmartApp", "after builder4");
    }

}
```

---

```
// datarobot class
public class DataRobot extends Activity {
/* This class is for analyzing the data */
private List _listeners = new ArrayList();
private List<DataAlertListener> _listeners2 = new ArrayList<DataAlertListener>();
private SmartDataObject data;
private int sI1;
private int sI2;
private float w1;
private float w2;
private float w3;
private int hRB;
private int hRVMin;
private int hRVMax;

public boolean analyzeData(SmartDataObject temp) {
    /* Analyze the data
     * Returns true if data was successfully analyzed
     * Returns false if an error occurred
     */
    data = temp;
    if(data.getHeartRate()>290) {
        fireDataAlertEvent();
    }
    fireDataAnalyzedEvent(data);
    return true; //for now this will always return true
}

public synchronized void addDataAnalyzedListener(DataAnalyzedListener listener) {
    _listeners.add(listener);
}
public synchronized void removeDataAnalyzedListener(DataAnalyzedListener listener) {
    _listeners.remove(listener);
}
private synchronized void fireDataAnalyzedEvent(SmartDataObject temp) {
    DataAnalyzedEvent dRE = new DataAnalyzedEvent(this, temp);
    Iterator listeners = _listeners.iterator();
    while(listeners.hasNext()) {
        ((DataAnalyzedListener)listeners.next()).dataAnalyzedReceived(dRE);
    }
}
public interface DataAnalyzedListener {
    public void dataAnalyzedReceived(DataAnalyzedEvent event);
}



public synchronized void addDataAlertListener(DataAlertListener listener) {
    _listeners2.add(listener);
}
public synchronized void removeDataAlertListener(DataAlertListener listener) {
    _listeners2.remove(listener);
}
private synchronized void fireDataAlertEvent() {
    DataAlertEvent dAE = new DataAlertEvent(this);
    Iterator listeners = _listeners2.iterator();
    while(listeners.hasNext()) {
        ((DataAlertListener)listeners.next()).dataAlertReceived(dAE);
    }
}
public interface DataAlertListener {
    public void dataAlertReceived(DataAlertEvent event);
}
}
```

---

```
public class DataAlertEvent extends EventObject {
    public DataAlertEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

---

**Below is the added code after trying to fix**

```
02-06 10:27:30.673: VERBOSE/SmartApp(276): data alert event caught
02-06 10:27:31.013: WARN/System.err(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-06 10:27:31.042: WARN/System.err(276):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
02-06 10:27:31.052: WARN/System.err(276):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:231)
02-06 10:27:31.052: WARN/System.err(276):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
02-06 10:27:31.062: WARN/System.err(276):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
02-06 10:27:31.082: WARN/System.err(276):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
02-06 10:27:31.082: WARN/System.err(276):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-06 10:27:31.102: WARN/System.err(276):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$4.dataAlertReceived(SmartApp.java:80)
02-06 10:27:31.102: WARN/System.err(276):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataRobot.fireDataAlertEvent(DataRobot.java:96)
02-06 10:27:31.122: WARN/System.err(276):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataRobot.analyzeData(DataRobot.java:32)
02-06 10:27:31.122: WARN/System.err(276):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$2.dataReceivedReceived(SmartApp.java:66)
02-06 10:27:31.133: WARN/System.err(276):     at cpe495.smartapp.ConnectDevice.fireDataReceivedEvent(ConnectDevice.java:71)
02-06 10:27:31.133: WARN/System.err(276):     at cpe495.smartapp.ConnectDevice.run(ConnectDevice.java:42)
02-06 10:27:31.153: WARN/System.err(276):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

---

```
public class SmartApp extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    TextView smartConnectionStatus;
    TextView testOutputView;
    Thread cThread;
    private ConnectDevice cD = new ConnectDevice();
    private DataRobot dR = new DataRobot();
    private DataBuilder dB = new DataBuilder();
    private DataSender dS = new DataSender();


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);

    final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    Log.v("SmartApp", "inside sendalert");
    //AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    Log.v("SmartApp", "after builder1");
    //Vibrator vibrator;
    //vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    //vibrator.vibrate(500);
    alert.setMessage("Testing alert dialog...");
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    Log.v("SmartApp", "after builder2");
    //AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Title");

        cD.addDataReceivedListener(new DataReceivedListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataReceivedReceived(DataReceivedEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dR.analyzeData(event.getData());
            }
        });
        dR.addDataAlertListener(new DataAlertListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataAlertReceived(DataAlertEvent event) {
                Log.v("SmartApp", "data alert event caught");
                sendAlert();
                            alert.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create and show alert dialog in UI thread or:

1. Create a Handler in UI thread.

   ```
   Handler mHandler = new Handler();
   ```
2. Create a thread

   ```
   class A implements Runnable {
       public void run() {
           // create and show alert here
       }
   }
   ```
3. When event is fired, call:

   ```
   A a = new A();
   mHandler.post(a);
   ```

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the help. I tried it yesterday but must have had something wrong. Working exactly as i needed. Thanks merrymenvn.

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); should be called from a UI Thread.Try moving the create() method to UI Thread.

Comment: I put the creating of the AlertDialog inside the OnCreate method in SmartApp. Then i moved the alert.show() to my dataAlertReceived function. I had to make the AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create() final for this to work. When the dialog is supposed to be called i get the logcat error attached to the OP. Please see OP for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This was the same error I was getting so thank yo for suggesting to put it on the UI thread. I'm working in Xamarin though and the solution for me was actually to put it on the main thread like this:

```
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            page.DisplayAlert("Alert", message, null, "Cancel");
        });
```